# How to load a resource from a .net core system resource file?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-core

With the .Net framework, I was using this code to load a string resource from the windows forms assembly:

```
ResourceManager systemRM = new ResourceManager("System.Windows.Forms", Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Form)));
var str = systemRM.GetString(<the resource name>);
```

Running this in .net core 3, I get a MissingManifestResourceException:

> "Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or
>   the neutral culture.  Make sure "System.resources" was correctly
>   embedded or linked into assembly "System.ComponentModel.Primitives" at
>   compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are
>   loadable and fully signed."

How to access this kind of system resource in .net core?
Thanks